# Read datetime with offset from SQL Server as datetime in R

Tags: r, sql-server, datetime, timezone, odbc

I have tables with datetime with offset in SQL Server:

```
datetime                              Value     Instance
--------------------------------------------------------
2021-06-18 03:48:30.0000000 +08:00    4194304   39069
2021-06-18 03:48:30.0000000 +08:00    1048576   39098
2021-06-18 03:48:30.0000000 +08:00     372736   39076
```

I am using ODBC library to query the SQL. The problem - I get column datetime as char. I have millions of records, so I spend minutes to convert datetime column to posixct which is too long wait for my tasks:

```
out_data %>% mutate (datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, tz=Sys.timezone()))
```

I am also loosing correct timezone during that convert. Is there any module that can query SQL and receive that datetime format as datetime?

Comment: My code in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68103906/3358272) already converted this string to a correct `POSIXt` object. It works on a vector of things strings, too. The _only_ limitation is that a vector of datetimes in R is always shown as the same time zone ... *but they are all correct times*.

Comment: The issue is not necessarily how to query it from SQL Server (since `odbc` does not know properly about `DATETIMEOFFSET`), you'll get it as strings, period. Since you already have code that correctly converts that string to a correct `POSIXt`, and I've identified a limitation of R's storage of a vector of timestamps. Perhaps the issue is the *presentation* of that data on your console?

Comment: I regularly pull 2M rows of data from SQL Server with at least one (often 2-4) column that is type `datetimeoffset`, and it comes to me as `character` (same as you). My process correctly parses the timezone from the string (using `gsub` and `format=` as in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68104756/3358272)) well within seconds, not minutes. How much data are you pulling, and/or how are you processing it so that it takes *"minutes to convert"*?

Comment: Your code: data_1 <- data_1 %>% 
  mutate (datetime = as.POSIXct(gsub(" ([-+]\\d{2}):(\\d{2})", " \\1\\2", datetime),
                                format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS %z")) converts date to this: "2021-06-17 22:48:30 MSK" which is correct datetime but with wrong time zone.  It was +8, now it's +3. I need to show original time at ggplot graphs - 03:48:30, not 22:38:30. I don't need to convert tz to my local one. I need to keep it as it was.

Comment: I don't know what to say ... with the data you provided, it doesn't provide the "MSK" output. But ... you didn't add `tz=` to your code there, so perhaps this should not be surprising?

Comment: Does it help to learn that the `tz=` argument only controls the timezone that it will be displayed in, and has nothing to do with the time zone that is inherently suggested by the string? For instance, you could use `tz=Sys.timezone()` or `tz="UTC"` or another timezone regardless if the datetimeoffset returned by the dbms ends in `"+08:00"` or `"-04:00"` or anything else. The `%z` directive dictates the timezone for interpreting the string, the `tz=` argument directs how it is displayed on the R console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key was to solve this problem on SQL side. If R receives data in datetime format - nothing to convert. So we need to convert datetime with offset to datetime.

SQL makes this very fast:

```
select CAST(datetime AS datetime) as 'datetime', Value, Instance from Perf
```